# Euclid Algorithm incorrect results

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to write a Java implementation of Euclid's algorithm: The body of my method looks like this:

```
    while(a%b != 0) {
        int newA = b * ((int) Math.floor(a/b));
        int newB = a - newA;

        a = newA;
        b = newB;
    }
    return a;
```

However, I keep getting results which are not correct... I think I have a logic error, but really can't understand where it is :\

Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't be using division operator [`/`] inside Euclidian division, you are supposed to implement it.

Comment: Can you show your unit test with inputs and the actual and expected outputs?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Try describing a) What you expected to happen b) What actually happened, and for utility c) Why you expected (a) to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Euclid algorithm, at each step a must be assigned the old b, and b must be assigned a%b. You're computing new value of b correctly, but for a you're computing something like `a =  a - a%b`.

For an easy fix, you could just replace the line where you're setting the value for a to simply this:

```
a = b;
```

(that is before setting the new b)

Answer (score 4):

Euclid's algorithm is the following:

1. If a < b, swap(a, b);
2. [a, b] = [b, a % b], until a % b == 0;
3. return b.

You code has multiple problems, but the more prominent one is that you are returning `a`, instead of `b`.

Another thing: don't try to reinvent the `%` (remainder) operator.

Comment: +1 for "don't reinvent `%`"; in fact, `%` is actually the _remainder_ operator, which is exactly what OP needs.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard edited, thanks. I know that `%` is not the math mod, but short circuited on the name.

Comment: Yeah. It's often referred to as modulo because the difference is pretty small (in fact when using it I always read "mod"). But since OP is trying to implement the Euclidean algorithm (which is defined using the remainder), it's worth noting that `%` is exactly that operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you greatly. [Euclid Algorithm in Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Euclid.java.html)

**Code**

```
// non-recursive implementation
public static int gcd2(int p, int q) {
    while (q != 0) {
        int temp = q;
        q = p % q;
        p = temp;
    }
    return p;
}
```